# PHP file connect Mysql display Blank page in Ubuntu OS

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

i want to run my PHP code in Ubuntu. This is my code
just want to display user in User table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Kgam Internship Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbConnect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db(kgam)or die(mysql_error());
if($dbConnect)
{
  echo "Database connected";
}else{
  echo "Database connect error";
}
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die(mysql_error());
print"<table width=100% border=1 cellpadding=3>";
print"<tr><td>ID</td><td>UUID</td><td>Name</td><td>Recently Status</td> </tr>";
$i = 0;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{
   # code...
   echo "Test".$i;
   print"<tr><td>".$info['id']."</td>";
   print "<td>".$info['uuid'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>".$info['uname'] ."</td>"; 
   print "<td>".$info['status'] ."</td></tr>"; 
   $i = $i + 1;

} 
print "</table>"; 
mysql_close($dbConnect);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

i try this code is work on my Window  please help me 
i have information in database on Ubuntu
my result when i ran this is blank page

Comment: Can you get the output from a simple php page on the ubuntu server? What is the source of your blank page, is it blank as well?

Comment: Depending on the version of PHP installed, mysql_ extensions are deprecated and so may not work.  You should move to either PDO or mysqli_ versions.

Comment: `mysql_select_db(kgam)` what is `kgam`. If `kgam` is actually the database name then enclose it in single quite like `mysql_select_db('kgam')`

Comment: Check `LAMP` is installed on your machine and also are you running it on `localhost`..?

Answer (score 0):

I hope error is in this line, you have to enter database name with in single quotes `mysql_select_db('kgam')`

Answer (score 0):

I can fixed my problem. i installed PHP 7.0 in Ubuntu and i need to use

> mysqli

instead of

> mysql

Now it's worked !!